# Talend Connectivity with Share Point

Tags: talend

Can anyone advise me how to make Share Point connectivity with TALEND and upload the file into Share Point?  I am trying to upload files into share point with the help of Talend. I have used tFileFetch component to upload a file into share point with credentials, while loading encountering error connection time out.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problematic, files would periodically be dropped in a folder and I had to send them to SharePoint.

So first for the authentication I created a joblet for that with all the necessary variables in context :

[image]

And inside I make the API call to get the token, extract it from the json and put it in the output of the joblet

[image]

Here is the configuration of the tRest componenent  :

[image]

with the context.URL_MicrosoftOnline = https://login.microsoftonline.com

and the body would be like :
`"grant_type="+row1.grant_type + "&client_id=" +row1.client_id + "&client_secret=" +row1.client_secret + "&scope=" +row1.scope`

Then to upload a file to SharePoint you need to send it as bytes array so to do it :

- I read the file as bytes array using a tFileInputRaw
  [image]

I then store it in a globalVar :

[image]

And for the upload API call :

[image]

the Content-Type is application/pdf for me because I upload PDF files, but it can be changed and the URL looks like this :

- [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{{ID_DRIVE/root:/{{destinationFolderPath}}/{{FILENAME}}:/content](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7B%7BID_DRIVE/root:/%7B%7BdestinationFolderPath%7D%7D/%7B%7BFILENAME%7D%7D:/content)

Hope this helps